# Como imprimir en php el post_id de esta consulta SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ';') FROM <nombre_tabla> GROUP BY post_id

Tags: php, sql

Buen día para todos. Soy principiante en programación y gracias a esta plataforma pude solucionar varias cosas, resulta que para lo que quiero hacer necesito darle la opción al usuario de filtrar los datos mostrados por medio del post_id de la consulta que describo en el titulo.Quisiera poner como primera columna un id correspondiente al post_id de la consulta. El codigo que uso es

$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR '|') FROM wpzj_postmeta WHERE post_id > 3848 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY meta_id DESC";

````
            $rs  = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

          foreach ($rs as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $keyD => $valueD) {
                $prueba = explode("|", $valueD);
                    
                ?>
            
                    <tr>
                        <td>pepito perez</td>
                        <td>1234567</td>
                        <td>Colombia</td>
                        <td>Lugar</td>
                        <td>Lugar</td>
                        <td>Cra 18 </td>
                        <td>32345678</td>
                        <?php ?>
                <td><?php echo $prueba[8]." ".$prueba[9] ?></td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo $prueba[15]; ?>  </td>
                        <td>Colombia</td>
                <td><?php echo $prueba[13]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prueba[12]; ?></td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo $prueba[19]." ".$prueba[20] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prueba[16]; ?></td>```
````

Comment: Pega también el código php donde haces tu consulta para saber cómo la estás pasando

Comment: Tendrías que incluir la columna `post_id` en el `SELECT`  y luego recuperarla. Conviene que uses un alias para el resultado del `GROUP_CONCAT` para así poder recuperar cada columna por su nombre mediante `fetch_assoc`

Comment: Si que pena la consulta si la puse sino que no se no se mostraba con el codigo esta es la consulta:
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR '|') FROM wpzj_postmeta WHERE post_id > 3848 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY meta_id DESC";